# What is a golden bitstream

Tags: imaging

In the context of boards, like framegrabbers....

if the bitstream fails it will go through the golden bitstream....

Something like that, can anyone put some light on this matter for me ?
I remember hearing about the subject in one of my meetings so do not have my hands on any manuals with the specific words

Comment: I believe this is a rarely used term for a reference bitstream, aka "This is what it's supposed to look like", but this isn't really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A golden bitstream may be used to configure a device with a design that has been tested and is stable and provide all basic functionality but may not fully support advanced or custom features.  Reference: Parallel interface for configuring programmable devices at:

http://www.freepatentsonline.com/7358762.html

For more information find "golden bitstream" in the above referenced web page and read the containing paragraphs about it.